# This and that when they refer to non-tangible objects

Tags: grammar, word-choice, connotation, conversation

Let's take this example:

> ....But on a regular, day-to-day basis, when a task requires thinking
> that isn’t itself enjoyable, even puzzle lovers’ brains prefer less
> thinking over more.
> **That** is the law of least mental effort.
>
> **This**, of course, has major implications for our decision making,

- Why in the 1st case it's "that", and in the 2nd "this"?
- What would happend if it was the opposite - this, then that - instead?
- What if there were 2 "this", or 2 "that" instead? How would the meaning have changed?

Comment: **"Why in the 1st case it's 'that', and in the 2nd 'this'?"** No reason. It's arbitrary. **"What would happend if it was the opposite - this, then that - instead?"** Nothing would happen. **What if there were 2 "this", or 2 "that" instead? How would the meaning have changed?** The meaning wouldn't change. The meaning would stay exactly the same if it were instead "this" and "this," "that" and "that," or "this" and "that."

Comment: This is used to refer to something nearby, close at hand, currently happening, or just mentioned; that is used to refer to something more distant, detached, or viewed from afar. Hence the choice of "this" and "that" can represent the writer's relationship with a topic. In the extract it's possible the law of least mental effort is being presented an external fact that has been known for a long time, while its effects are something they emphasize closeness to.

Comment: @StuartF and which is more distant and which is more far in my example? And how have you measured it?

Comment: @BenjaminHarman I see.